# Wrong SLD style generated by QGIS for Geoserver

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

can you tell me what is wrong with following SLD style? I've generated it by QGIS (2.18.3). In QGIS styles works fine, but when I upload it into Geoserver (2.10.1) and click valide I've had a lot of errors: 
[image]

Legend of SLD does not works too:

[image]

Here is my generated SLD:
http://pastebin.com/GLp4xfx1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your filters are broken:

```
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:Literal>motorway</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

should probably be something like:

```
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
         <ocg:PropertyIsEqual>
            <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>motorway</ogc:Literal>
         </ocg:PropertyIsEqual>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: thanks, I fix filters, but next I must fix conditions